# SPSS Statistics

Tags: statistics, spss

my PC changed but I would like to continue with SPSS test version on my new one. HOw can I deactivate the test Version on the old one? It is already deinstalled.
Thanks a lot.
Best regards
Henriette

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply install your test version on the new machine and to see if that works out? 
According to [this IBM support page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21985888),

> A valid Authorized User product authorization code can be used to license up to two (2) product installations used by the same individual.

That might hold true for test versions as well, so maybe you can just reinstall it and carry on. 
Otherwise, it never does any harm to write IBM support a quick e-mail describing your problem, as license transfer should be a routine situation for most software developers.